# Vue3 - vue-cli-plugin-i18n - Can't change language dynamically

Tags: vuejs3, vue-i18n

I am actually trying to follow this video tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFGjn3yKMNc

**Summary of the problem : I can't change the language dynamically with i18n. It stays on the language i18n was initialised with.**

So, my i18n uses a different json file for each languages :

> locales/en.json containing : { "message" : "hello world"}

> locales/fr.json containing : { "message" : "bonjour"}

In the `i18n.js` (below) files, if I change `locale` value to `en`, "hello world" is displayed, and if I put `fr` instead of `en`, "bonjour" is displayed. Works Ok.

This code is what came with the installation of i18n except for the `.default`

```
function loadLocaleMessages() {
    const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
    const messages = {}
    locales.keys().forEach(key => {
        const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
        if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
            const locale = matched[1]
            messages[locale] = locales(key).default

        }
    })
    console.log(messages)
    return messages
}

export default createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true,
    locale: 'fr',
    fallbackLocale: 'fr',
    messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

The default language is `fr`
Now, in my `main.js`, I have the code below.
The goal is to pass a lang parameter in the URL. This work, I get the param.
Unfortunately, even if the param is set to `'en'`, `bonjour` is still displayed.
I tried to force it by replacing `i18n.locale = language` with `i18n.locale = 'en'`, no luck.
In fact, in the console, even if the `i18n.locale` value is set to `'en'`, it still displays french.

However, like I said, if I replace the `locale: 'fr',` in the code **above** `with locale: 'en',` it works...

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    let language = to.params.lang;
    if (!language) {
        language = 'en'
    }
    i18n.locale = language
    console.log("Active locale: ", i18n.locale)
    next()
})


const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.use(i18n)
app.mount('#app')
```

Does Anybody has a clue of why it is not working although the i18n.locale value is changed to 'en' ?

Thank you for your time :)

My version of i18n and vue are

> ```
> "vue": "^3.0.0",
> "vue-i18n": "^9.1.6"
> "@intlify/vue-i18n-loader": "^2.1.0",
> "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
> "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
> "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
> "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
> "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "~2.1.1"
> ```

Comment: Hi could you try tu run the `i18n.locale = language` logic inside the component? My guess is that there is some problem with the scope of the language change as it seems to not b applied to the component.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm interested in a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved by changing the router.beforeEach(...) to:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    let language = to.params.lang

    if (!language) {
    language = 'fr'
    }

    i18n.global.locale.value = language
    next()
})
```